# (g)vim tab key doesn't suggest anything when opening a file or splitting window

Tags: vim, tabs, key

I don't understand why my (g)vim doesn't suggest anything when I try to open another file or to split the window. When I use the tab key to complete the file name, a "^I" (capital i) appears instead.

e.g. ":split ev^I" when I know there is a file named event_queue.adb in the current directory...

Answer (score 2):

It works for me as expected, so I can't easily tell what the problem may be. However, does `:set wildmenu` help at all? If not, how about if you set `wildchar` to a non-tab key (e.g. `:set wildchar=$` or `:set wildchar=$`? Also if you have `wildchar` set to other than tab, that could cause the problem you see and `:set wildchar=<Tab>` would fix it.